# Printing Matplotlib Title from pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I need to print a title for a few plots in a loop with string values from a dataframe. I have managed to create a loop to plot graphs, however I have trouble with said Titles, which are neccessary.

This is the code I've used:

```
for i in range (len(resultXDataFrame.index)):
    selected_row = i
    selected_result = result.iloc[selected_row, 17:]
    selected_etalon = etalon.iloc[selected_row, 17:]
    plt.figure()
    plt.title(result.loc[selected_row, 'DEPARTMENT'], 'MONTH ', result.loc[selected_row, 'M'], 'YEAR', result.loc[selected_row, 'Y'])
    x_axis = np.arange(0, predict_length, 1)
    plt.plot(x_axis, selected_result, color = 'black')
    plt.plot(x_axis, selected_etalon, color = 'red')
    plt.xlim(0, predict_length)
    plt.xlabel('Prediction length in days')
    plt.ylabel('Predicted Illness')
    plt.show()
```

However I receive an error saying:

```
TypeError: title() takes from 1 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

The problem is definetly on the line where I try to define the title. When I choose a fixed title, it works just fine. I just need to concat the part of:

```
plt.title(result.loc[selected_row, 'DEPARTMENT'], 'MONTH ', result.loc[selected_row, 'M'], 'YEAR', result.loc[selected_row, 'Y'])
```

So it prints the correct title for each of my graph, which should look like that:

> DEPARTMENT XXX MONTH X YEAR XXXX

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT!

```
#plot results for selected department
for i in range (len(resultXDataFrame.index)):
    selected_row = i
    selected_result = result.iloc[selected_row, 17:]
    selected_etalon = etalon.iloc[selected_row, 17:]
    plt.figure()
    plt.title(str(result.loc[selected_row, 'DEPARTMENT']) + ' MONTH ' + str(result.loc[selected_row, 'M']) + ' YEAR ' + str(result.loc[selected_row, 'Y']))
    x_axis = np.arange(0, predict_length, 1)
    plt.plot(x_axis, selected_result, color = 'black')
    plt.plot(x_axis, selected_etalon, color = 'red')
    plt.xlim(0, predict_length)
    plt.xlabel('Prediction length in days')
    plt.ylabel('Predicted Illness')
    plt.show()
```